# Is there any way to identify multiple polygons at GEE and find their time series NDVI?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel2

I'm relatively new to Google Earth Engine (GEE), and I have a task involving 12 polygons on GEE. I would like to calculate the time series of NDVI for each of these polygons and subsequently compare their NDVI trends over two different years using Sentinel-2 data.

I'm seeking assistance on how to properly identify and analyze the time series data for each polygon. Specifically, I would like to understand how to distinguish between the different polygons and efficiently compare their NDVI values over the specified time periods. Any guidance or assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

i am trying to individually calculate all the polygon timeseries data and collectively as well but in collectively all polygon take as a geometry then apply time series NDVI function. what i need how to identify each polygon in it and its NDVI.